# Specifying the database name with SQLite3 when using self.table_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I have a has_many that goes across multiple databases, for example:

```
class Foo
  establish_connection :database1
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar
end
```

Under normal circumstances things are okay.. Foo uses database1 and Bar uses the Rails environment database (according to database.yml). Unfortunately the association is broken:

```
Table 'database1.bars' doesn't exist
```

I've read several places online that I need to specify the database name specifically with `self.table_name=`. SQLite3 doesn't seem to have a database name though? I'd like to do

```
self.table_name = '<something>.bars'
```

in my Bar model. Is this possible with SQLite3?

Comment: So, did you have a chance to try my suggestion? Did it work?

Answer (score 1):

By default SQLite creates a database called `main` attached to `.db` file. So you can try to refer to `main` database as follows:

```
self.table_name = 'main.bars'
```

More info in the second paragraph of [ATTACH DATABASE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) official documentation.

**Note:** Not sure if it will work on Ruby I've just tried directly on sqlite as follows:

```
D:\sqlite3>sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> CREATE TABLE User(user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR);
sqlite> INSERT INTO User(name) VALUES('dic19');
sqlite> INSERT INTO User(name) VALUES('Logan Serman');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM User;
1|dic19
2|Logan Serman
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main             D:\sqlite3\test.db
sqlite> SELECT * FROM main.User;
1|dic19
2|Logan Serman
sqlite>
```

Using `.databases` command you can get a list of all names and files of attached databases :

```
.databases             List names and files of attached databases
```

**Screenshot**

[image]